# Typescript - Tried to make a react-native slider from scratch and facing a few problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slider

The following code is everything I have written and since I am new to all this, I am sure there are a lot of mistakes.

Slider Component Usage:

```
 const trackMarks = [
    { value: 100, name: 'Min1' },
    { value: 250, name: 'Start' },
    { value: 500, name: 'Quarter' },
    { value: 750, name: 'Half' },
    { value: 1000, name: 'Max1' },
  ];

<Slider maximumValue={10} minimumValue={5} step={5} onValueChange={handleValueChange} />
          <Slider maximumValue={50} minimumValue={25} onValueChange={handleValueChange} />
          <Slider maximumValue={50000} minimumValue={25000} step={5000} onValueChange={handleValueChange} />
          <Slider maximumValue={100} minimumValue={50} step={10} onValueChange={handleValueChange} />
          <Slider maximumValue={1000} minimumValue={100} trackMarks={trackMarks} onValueChange={handleValueChange} />
          <SText>SliderValue: {sliderValue}</SText>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HBdE.gif)
```

Slider Code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, PanResponder, View, Image, ImageSourcePropType, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const TRACK_WIDTH = 200; // Define the fixed track width
const RANGE = 100;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Styles for the slider components
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    // backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height: 25,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  trackTextContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: TRACK_WIDTH,
  },
  trackText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: 'black',
  },
  track: {
    height: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#999999',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  thumbImage: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
});

// Type definition for individual track marks on the slider
type TrackMark = {
  value: number;
  name: string;
};

// Props for the Slider component
type SliderProps = {
  maximumValue: number;
  minimumValue: number;
  step?: number;
  trackMarks?: TrackMark[];
  thumbImage?: ImageSourcePropType;
  onValueChange?: (value: number) => void;
};

// The Slider component
const Slider = ({ maximumValue, minimumValue, step, trackMarks = [], thumbImage, onValueChange }: SliderProps) => {
  // Animated value to represent the thumb's position
  const thumbValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(minimumValue)).current;
  const value_range = maximumValue - minimumValue;

  // PanResponder to handle thumb gestures
  const thumbPanResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      // Allow the PanResponder to respond to gesture
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,

      // Update the thumbValue based on the gesture movement
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dx: thumbValue }], {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),

      // Handle thumb release
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gestureState) => {
        console.log('gesture', gestureState.dx);
        const normalizedGesture = Math.min(RANGE, Math.max(0, gestureState.dx));
        console.log('normalized gesture', normalizedGesture);

        let value = normalizedGesture;
        // Snapping logic based on step or trackMarks
        if (step) {
          const normalizedStep = (step / value_range) * RANGE;
          value = Math.floor(value / normalizedStep + 0.5) * normalizedStep;
          console.log('step value', value);
        } else if (trackMarks.length > 0) {
          const normalizedTrackMarks = [
            { value: 0, name: 'Min' }, // Add min as a normalized track mark
            ...trackMarks.map(mark => ({
              ...mark,
              value: ((mark.value - minimumValue) / value_range) * RANGE,
            })),
            { value: RANGE, name: 'Max' }, // Add max as a normalized track mark
          ];
          console.log('normalized track marks', normalizedTrackMarks);
          const nearestMark = normalizedTrackMarks.reduce((mark, closest) =>
            Math.abs(value - mark.value) < Math.abs(value - closest.value) ? mark : closest,
          );
          console.log('nearest mark', nearestMark);
          value = nearestMark.value;
        }

        const denormalizeValue = Math.ceil((value / RANGE) * value_range + minimumValue);

        console.log('value', value);
        console.log('actual value', denormalizeValue);
        console.log('');

        // Perform a spring animation to smoothly update the thumb's position
        Animated.spring(thumbValue, {
          toValue: value,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start(() => {
          // Call the onValueChange callback if provided
          if (onValueChange) {
            onValueChange(denormalizeValue);
          }
        });
      },
    }),
  ).current;

  // Calculate the position of the thumb based on its value
  const thumbPosition = thumbValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, RANGE],
    outputRange: [0, TRACK_WIDTH],
    extrapolate: 'clamp', // Keep thumb within the valid range
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Display track marks */}
      <View style={styles.trackTextContainer}>
        {trackMarks.map((mark, index) => (
          <View
            key={index}
            style={[{ left: ((mark.value - minimumValue) / value_range) * TRACK_WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'white' }]}
          >
            {/* Display track mark names below the track */}
            <Text style={styles.trackText}>{mark.name.length > 1 ? mark.name.substring(0, 1) : mark.name}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
      {/* Track background */}
      <View>
        <View style={[styles.track, { width: TRACK_WIDTH }]} />
        {/* Animated thumb */}
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.thumb,
            {
              transform: [{ translateX: thumbPosition }],
              left: -10,
              top: -5,
            },
          ]}
          {...thumbPanResponder.panHandlers} // Attach PanResponder handlers
        >
          {thumbImage && <Image source={thumbImage} style={styles.thumbImage} />}
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

There are mainly three things I have not been able to achieve with the provided code snippet for a pure react-native slider:

1. The name of the Track Marks despite being multiplied by TRACK_WIDTH (to normalize and index the values on the slider) do not seem to match the length of the track.
2. Every time I try to pull the thumb on the slider for the second time it snaps back to the beginning and then only starts moving right i.e., idk what code to change to be able to make the slider move forward and backward normally. [Click here for error visualization !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXSeu.gif)
3. There might be multiple redundant code as I am a beginner. Feel free to point those out. Thank you.